# How can I parse the contents of a PDF file in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-html

Is there a way I can parse the contents of `PDF` files into widgets or something more understandable or perhaps into something that can be modified and again converted to PDF format?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [pdf library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to achieve this task

```
import 'dart:io'; 
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart' as pw;
```

Import like this and then use following method to extract text from pdf

```
String loadPdf({required String pdfPath}) {
  String text = "";
  // Load the PDF file
  var file = File(pdfPath);
  var bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();

  // Decode the PDF file
  var pdf = pw.PdfDocument.fromBytes(bytes);

  // Extract the text from the PDF

  for (var page in pdf.pages) {
    var pageText = page.getText();
    text += pageText;
  }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: The `fromBytes()` method/constructor does not seem to exist on the PdfDocument class. Where did you get it from?

I'm also trying to read a PDF using just Dart (i.e. not full-fledged Flutter), and most PDF-related packages require `dart:ui` which necessitates Flutter.

The `pdf` package seems to be the only one without such constraint, but I cannot figure out how to make it read an existing PDF. Seems it's only intended to generate new PDF files.

Comment: @Kalex Were you able to find any package? I am also in need of some simple dart/flutter library to read the text from the pdf document. Unable to find any!

Comment: @Sumanth not yet. I've put that side-project on hold in the meantime, but new alternatives may have come out since.

Comment: @Kalex Could not find any which can support all clients such as Android, iOs and web.