# How can I extract text from a PDF document in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdftotext

I am working on a Flutter application and need to extract text from PDF documents. I have attempted to use the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package, but I'm unable to do so as I can see only PdfDocumentParserBase which is an abstract class that is present.

I don't see any implementation of the same class.

Here is snippet from my code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';

void _processFileContents(html.File file) async {
  setState(() {
    _isProcessing = true;
    _processingText = "Please wait";
  });

  final reader = html.FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  await reader.onLoad.first;

  final List<int> bytes = reader.result as List<int>;

  // Process the contents of the file as needed
  final pdfDocument = PdfDocument.load(pdfDocumentParser); // I am not sure how to get this pdfDocumentParser

  // Extract text from each page of the PDF
  final List<String> pdfText = [];
  for (var page in pdfDocument.pages!) {
    pdfText.add(page.text!);
  }

  // Display or process extracted text as needed
  print(pdfText);

  setState(() {
      _isProcessing = false;
      _processingText = "";
      _isPdfProcessed = true;
  });
  });
}
```

I have already tried the pdf package as mentioned in the detail.
I don't see much documentation in the internet and in the stackoverflow hence reaching out.

I have also checked similar question: [How can I parse the contents of a PDF file in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664732/how-can-i-parse-the-contents-of-a-pdf-file-in-dart)
There are no good answers in that thread too.

Can you please recommend me any other good package or the right way to use pdf package to extract text from a pdf document?

Any guidance or assistance with these issues would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The `pdf` package is designed to CREATE PDF files.  You can rearrange the pages in an existing document, but it can't read the text.  Perhaps you could use a command-line tool.

Comment: Thanks @KJ for your response.
But this package is supported only on Android or iOS. I need it to support web too.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your response. You are right since there are no flutter packages I might have to look at any other cloud function / command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

After 24h of searching the web I finally found that package [syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^24.2.9](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf#extract-text) that perform exactly the desired feature of extracting text from pdf document.
Here's how to use it with few lines of code :

```
Uint8List bytes = yourFile.readAsBytes();
final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(inputBytes: bytes);
String content = PdfTextExtractor(document).extractText();
document.dispose();
```